# why my python dictionary sort function doesn't work?

Tags: python, python-2.7

this code is supposed to sort the dictionary based on the value of each key.
the function compare each element in list(which is dictionary list) with index (x) to element with index (x+1).if it's smaller change the position.

```
def srt(dic):
    Als= list()
    Bls= list()
    ls = dic.keys()

    glenth = len (ls)
    count=0
    t=0
    while t < 200000:
        for x in range(0,len(ls)):
            count +=1
            A_value = dic[(ls[x])]

            if count >= len(ls):
                B_value = dic[(ls[count-1])]
                count -=1
            else:
                B_value = dic[(ls[count])]
            if A_value > B_value:
                continue
            else:
                A = ls[count-1]
                B = ls[count]
                ls[count-1] = B
                ls[count]  = A
    t +=1

    return ls

dic = dict()
dic = {'baraa':4,'Mohamed':30,'ali':40,'Mirghani':7,'Abuzaid':12,'ElonMask':3,'Jobs':1}
lst = srt(dic)
for x in lst:
    print x,dic[x]
```

Comment: So why don't just use `sorted()`?

Comment: Indeed, just `lst = sorted(dic, key=lambda x: dic[x])`

Comment: @KevinGuan It does work, both on python2 and python3. It returns the list of names, ordered by their numeric value (_Jobs_ comes first, then _ElonMask_, then _baraa_…).

Comment: @spectras I've deleted my comment, now I understand what's OP looking for...

Comment: He has some sort of odd bubble-sort in his function. (btw, the line above can be done slightly more efficiently, though a bit more "magical", with `lst = sorted(dic, key=dic.__getitem__)`)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for OrderedDict.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

dic ={'baraa':4,'Mohamed':30,'ali':40,'Mirghani':7,'Abuzaid':12,'ElonMask':3,'Jobs':1}
ordered_dic = OrderedDict(sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda t:t[1]))
print ordered_dic
```

output:

```
OrderedDict([('Jobs', 1), ('ElonMask', 3), ('baraa', 4), ('Mirghani', 7), ('Abuzaid', 12), ('Mohamed', 30), ('ali', 40)])
```

the ordered_dic is sorted by value of dic and then just use it as a normal dict. for example:

```
for k, v in ordered_dic.items():
    print k, v
```

this gives you:

```
Jobs 1
ElonMask 3
baraa 4
Mirghani 7
Abuzaid 12
Mohamed 30
ali 40
```